# Figuring out coordinate format contained in SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY attribute

Tags: oracle, geolocation, gis

I am working with some data which specifies an installation path, in another data source I have the location of events based on their lat/long location.

The installation location contained in the oracle attribute SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY does not match any X/Y geographic coordinate system I am familiar with (Lat/Long or UTM). Is there a way to figure out what the data type is that is stored in the SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY?

Here is an example of the data for a path with 3 (x,y) points:

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2002,1026911,NULL,
MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),
MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(
1352633.64991299994289875030517578125,
12347411.6615570001304149627685546875,
1352638.02988700009882450103759765625,
12347479.02890899963676929473876953125,
1352904.06293900008313357830047607421875,
12347470.76137300021946430206298828125,
))
```

The above should be roughly within the proximity to 33.9845° N, 117.5159° W, and I went through various conversions but could not find anything that led me anywhere close to the above.

I read through the documentation on SDO_GEOMETRY from the oracle page and did not find any help in figuring out what the data type is.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-object-type.htm#SPATL494

Alternatively, if there is a way I can type in the lat/long somewhere to see all of the different coordinate types which are equivalent, I might also be able to figure out which format this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a typo inside `MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2002,1026911,NULL,`

`1026911` is supposed to be a SRS - Spatial Reference System.

If we remove the first `1` we have `102691`, and that is a very well known SRS code.

[`ESRI:102691`](https://epsg.io/102691) for `NAD 1983 for StatePlane Minnesota North FIPS 2201 Feet`

The corresponding WKT gives you all the necessary information to perform any coordinate conversion:

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_Minnesota_North_FIPS_2201_Feet",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",2624666.666666666],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",328083.3333333333],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-93.09999999999999],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",47.03333333333333],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",48.63333333333333],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",46.5],
    UNIT["Foot_US",0.30480060960121924],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","102691"]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I looked through the link you provided and the WKT for quite some time but I am having trouble understanding how to take the WKT and extract the lat/long from my data.

Also I see there is a 2002, could it be possible that the 2002 is referencing this coordinate? https://epsg.io/2002 

I'm sorry for the questions, but this is all new territory for me!

Comment: The first thing to do is in case you can confirm there's a typo, correct all the tables where the SRS is wrong. Second, that information is only important if you want to transform the data to another SRS. The typical example is setting the SRS to WGS84 in order to overlay on Google Maps, for example. In that case better be familiar with a desktop GIS, like QGIS. The WKT can be used as a companion file for a shapefile.

Comment: The place where `2002` is, is supposed to be the element type ID. For example, Point, line, polygon, ... Nothing to do with the SRS.

Comment: I see. Thank you for pointing out QGIS and WGS84, it looks like a great point for me to start.